# cannot resolve sumbol

Tags: java

Привет. У меня такой вопрос, в проекте есть такой импорт:

```
android.support.v4.media.transportmediator
```

но он подчеркивается серым цветом - и транспортмедиатор выделяется красным цветом.

Вот фрагмент кода:

```
ed.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener () {

    @Override
    public void onClick (View view) {
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask () {

            public void run () {
                ScrollView.fullScroll (TransportMediator.KEYCODE_MEDIA_RECODER);
            }
        }, (long) 150);
    }
});
```

Он подчеркивается красным цветом `KEYCODE_MEDIA_RECODER`.

Я использую android studio 3.0.1.

Помогите решить проблему.

Comment: Импорт именно такой `android.support.v4.media.transportmediator`? Просто Java - регистрозависимый язык и вроде как нужно импортировать `android.support.v4.media.TransportMediator`

Comment: Да,именно такой импорт .

Answer (score -1):

```
 TransportMediator. KEYCODE_MEDIA_RECODER
```

Тут пробел уберите

```
 TransportMediator.KEYCODE_MEDIA_RECODER
```

И в остальных случаях пробел после точки не ставится

Comment: Ваш ответ не дал результата.

Comment: @Виктор честно говоря, джавушке плевать на эти пробелы, можно заставиться и перед точкой, и после, даже можно добавить переносы строк, если захочется :)

Comment: @AlexChermenin и в правду. Просто как-то привык, глаз замозолило от такого написания, это как ставить запятую после пробела ,вроде не важно ,но напрягает немного =)